# How do I validate a settings(ini) file for the values expected using bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

After I check if the ini file exists where it is expected to be, which I've learned how to do, I would like to check the file for proper formatting. I'd like to validate any number of "site" entries in the file and check that each entry adheres to the pattern below including the new line.

```
 1| [site1]
 2| shortcut=x1
 3| site=example1.com
 4| theme=alpha
 5|
 6| [site2]
 7| shortcut=x2
 8| site=example2.com
 9| theme=beta
10|
```

I've got the individual values being validated as they are being read. I just want to make sure the pattern is correct before processing the file echoing the line number where the pattern breaks if it isn't.

Comment: so you want to check validity of `.ini` syntax right?

Comment: You need a parser.

Comment: Yes, that is my intent @pqnet . My apologies for the delay, I had to step out.

Comment: write a parser in something other than bash.

Answer (score 2):

You could try crudini

```
crudini --get file.ini |
while read section; do
  test "$(crudini --get t.ini $section | paste -d, - - -)" = \
       'shortcut,site,theme' ||
    echo error in section $section
done
```

Answer (score 0):

As a possible option:

```
BEGIN{
    FS="="
}
{
    if ($1~/\[.*\]/) {
        in_section=1;
        sec_name=$1
        next
    };
    if ($1~/^$/) {
        if ((c!=3) || (err)) {
            print "error in section "sec_name 
        };
        in_section=0; 
        sec_name="";
        c=0;
        err=0
    };
    if (in_section) {
        if ($1=="shortcut") {c++; next};
        if ($1=="site")     {c++; next};
        if ($1=="theme")    {c++; next};
        err=1
    };
}
END{
     if (in_section) {
        print "error in section "sec_name
    };
}
```